# c# - problem with returning value on Click event

Tags: c#

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintBoard();
    
    playerShip1 = PlaceBoats(Position.Vertical);
    playerShip2 = PlaceBoats(Position.Horizontal);
}

public void PlaceBoats(Position position)
{
    if (position == Position.Vertical)
    {
        foreach (var tile in playerBoard)
        {
            tile.MouseHover += (sender, EventArgs) => { Tile_MouseHover(sender, EventArgs, position); };
            tile.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { Place_Boat(sender, EventArgs, position); };
        }
    }
}

public int Place_Boat(object sender, EventArgs e, Position position)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    while (inRange)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(playerBoard, sender);
        Console.WriteLine($"index {index} on playerBoard");
        if (position == Position.Vertical)
        {
            if (index < 90)
            {
                playerBoard[index].Image = Properties.Resources.boatTop;
                playerBoard[index + 10].Image = Properties.Resources.boatBottom;
                playerShots[index] = "b";
                playerShots[index + 10] = "b";

            }
            else
            {
                //PROBLEM HERE - WANT TO RESTART THE FUNCTION
                inRange = false;
                MessageBox.Show("The vertical boat won't fit. Play stay in a higher range"); 
            }
        }
        else if (position == Position.Horizontal)
        {
            playerBoard[index].Image = Properties.Resources.boatTop;
            playerBoard[index + 1].Image = Properties.Resources.boatBottom;
            playerShots[index] = "b";
            playerShots[index + 1] = "b";
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

My goal is to return the index to where the user clicks on the board.
My problem is that, if the user clicks in the last row, it throws an IndexOutOfRange error. The code as is can't run for many reasons, but mostly because I have trouble return value error, which I understand : `Place_Boat : not all code paths return a value`.

In order to achieve this, I was thinking of returning the index if the click index is in range, and if not **restart the function**. I don't want to return anything else, because I need the value in order to move on the the next boat let's say. `playerShip2`.

I'm not exactly sure how to implement this... putting for instance a `while (inRange)` loop at the beginning before `playerShip1 = PlaceBoats(Position.Vertical)`.. but it doesn't sound very pretty.

Any ideas?

EDIT I realize here `PlaceBoats` is `void`, though I'm asking to get a value from it.
So I'd like to get the value of the index of the Picturebox clicked, maybe have it returned in `PlaceBoats` so that `playerShip1` can have it.

Thank you.

EDIT 2 : As it seems complicated to return value on events, I took another approach. I returned all the functions to return `void` and finally made my code look more straightforward. After `PrintBoard()` I call `PlaceBoats()` once, in which I call the `tile.Click += Place_Boat()`. I positioned a counter in the latter, to know if we position the boat vertically or horizontally. And just 3 boats. Then we load the rest.

Comment: What are you intending to do with that return value? In the shown code it is completely ignored

Comment: I edited to include some end braces `}` . Do they also miss in your real code?

Comment: My code doesn't throw an error for missed braces, sorry. I indeed might have jumped a step. I want to return the index value of the clicked PictureBox. And assign it to `playerShip1` etc..

Comment: I think you should have `int index = Array.IndexOf(playerBoard, sender);` above the `while`  and then move `return index;` to the bottom. I don't knnow if that's what you want but you will get rid of that error.

Comment: @m3.b - If you can't place a boat on certain tiles then it seems logical that you should attach the `Click`  event to those tiles in the first place.

Comment: Good point. I think What I'm having also trouble with in the end is limit the number of click event to 3 (or the number of boats the player can have).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, and avoid having the IndexoutofRange error, @enigmativity rightfully pointed to limit the click event only to the tile that should be clicked.

I was able to do so by modifying `PlaceBoats`  as :

```
public void PlaceBoats(Position position)
    {

        foreach (var (tile, index) in playerBoard.Select((Name, index) => (Name, index)))
        {
            if (position == Position.Vertical)

            {

                if (index < 90)
                {
                    tile.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { Place_Boat(sender, EventArgs, position); };
                }
            }
            else if (position == Position.Horizontal)
            {
                if (index % 10 < 9)
                {
                    tile.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => { Place_Boat(sender, EventArgs, position); };
                }

                //return index;
            }
           
        }
```

I'm actually now facing a new problem, as I can't seem to be able to return a value of the clickEvent. I need to limit the number of click event to the number of boat allowed to be place. I'm working on it, may ask about it later!

Thank you

Answer (score -3):

`int index = Array.IndexOf(playerBoard, sender);`

```
while (inRange){ rest of code }
```

Place int outside of while loop. Hope this helps.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It does not, sorry.